# Recursion java - Testing is the sum of the two Integers are equal Boolean function

Tags: java, recursion

I have Write a recursive function that accepts two integers. The function returns true if the first number digit amount equal to the second number, otherwise the function returns false.

the function always return true.

What am I doing wrong?

The code:

```
public static boolean amountEqual(int num1, int num2) {
    int sum1 = 0, sum2 = 0;

    if (num1 == 0 && num2 == 0 && sum1 == sum2)
        return true;
    else if (num1 == 0 && num2 == 0 && sum1 != sum2)
        return false;

    sum1 += num1 % 10;
    sum2 += num2 % 10;

    return amountEqual(num1 / 10, num2 / 10);
}
```

thank's

Comment: What is the purpose of your two variables `sum1` and `sum2`?

Comment: Each invocation has its own version of `sum1` and `sum2`. If you wan't to share a state between calls, pass it as an argument. Refrain from the urge to use global/instance vars.

Comment: sum1 = sum of all the digits of the first number
Sum2 = sum of all the digits of the second number

Answer (score 3):

> What am I doing wrong?

You are using `sum` that is always zero. You need to figure out a way to pass your `sum1` and `sum2` along, so that the final invocation could make a decision based on all prior invocations.

One way of doing it is by making the recursive function with four parameters, and adding a two-parameter overload to start the recursive chain:

```
public static boolean amountEqual(int num1, int num2) {
    return amountEqual(num1, num2, 0, 0);
}
private static boolean amountEqual(int num1, int num2, int sum1, int sum2) {
    ... // your recursive code goes here
}
```

Another approach is to compute digit differential, i.e. sum of digits in `num1` minus sum of digits in `num2`, and return `true` if the differential is zero:

```
public static boolean amountEqual(int num1, int num2) {
    return digitDifferential(num1, num2) == 0;
}
private static int digitDifferential(int num1, int num2) {
    return (num1 != 0 || num2 != 0)
    ? num1%10 - num2%10 + digitDifferential(num1/10, num2/10)
    : 0;
}
```

Comment: FWIW one could squash `sum1` and `sum2` into one parameter `sum` if the digits from `num1` are added to `sum` and the digits from `num2` are subtracted from `sum2`. But that's just nitpicking.

Comment: @MargaretBloom That's a very smart idea! I suggested another approach based on computing digit differential and returning `true` when it comes back as zero. Thanks!

Comment: That second approach is what I was just about to propose too, but with a slight improvement: Skip the last recursion call (and the extra div/mod calculations that go with it) by doing `num1 < 10 && num2 < 10 ? num1 - num2 : ...`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your question is unclear. I assumed that you want function to return true if digit sums of both numbers are equal.

Second, you're assuming that numbers are of equal length and they might not be.

Third, you're not passing `sum1` and `sum2` as paramethers.

Easier approach would be to make two functions, like this:

```
public static int digitSum(int num) {
    if (num > 0) {
        return num % 10 + digitSum(num / 10);
    }
    else
        return 0;
}

public static boolean amountEqual(int num1, int num2) {
    return digitSum(num1) == digitSum(num2);
}
```

Comment: Why `/=` when `/` is all you need? --- Skip a recursion by doing `if (num < 10) return num;`

Comment: They are not assuming both numbers have equal length. The code terminates when both numbers are zero, true, but since the non significant digits are zero, number with different lengths are implicitly supported.

Answer (score 0):

the first two line of your code every time you call the amountEqual method 
it initialize two new variables with zeros 
lets trace your recursion

```
System.out.println(amountEqual(18,26));
      /* F(20,30) = F(18/10,26/10) [sum1 = 8 , sum2 = 6] 
           re init sum1 = 0 , sum2 =0

            F(1,2)  = F(1/10,2/10) [ sum1 = 1 , sum2 = 2] 
           re init sum1 = 0 , sum2 = 0 
                    F(0,0) = true */
```